# VIM how to add certain html tags to the start or end of a line?

Tags: html, vim, tags

using...
   `2,40s/^/foo`
I can add stuff to the start of line(s) in VIM.

using...
   `2,40s/$/foo`
I can add stuff to the end of line(s) in VIM.

My question is...  How can I add certain html tags to the end or start of a line in vim?

Example..

`2,40s/$/</li>`     -  This command does not work.  I can add `<li>` to the end or start, but when I add '/' to it making the closing tag `</li>` it doesn't allow it.

I also came across this problem when trying to add 2,40s/^/&nbsp to the start of some lines.  The '&' character breaks the replace.

Is it possible to be able to add certain tags to vim lines, such as `</li>` or & anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape special characters like **/** and **&** with **\**

Example:

```
2,40s/^/<pre>
2,40s/$/<\/pre>
2,40s/^/\&nbsp;
```

If you don't want to escape slashes you can use custom delimiter, in this case **#**:

```
2,40s#$#</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other approach would be to use visual block mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, select all the line, then use <kbd>A</kbd>, type your tag `</foo>` , then <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

It will add `</foo>` at the end of every line.